# check collision of lines and a circle in canvas android

Tags: android, function, android-canvas, collision, lines

I am trying to check collisions between lines and a circle, if the circle hits the line, it would work change a boolean to true and once its not touched, it would change it back to false. I am using canvas and surface view.

Here is my code for checking collision which didn't work and ended up in error:

```
@Override
public void run() {
while(runnable)
    {
        if(!holder.getSurface().isValid()){
            continue;
        }
        Canvas mCanvas = holder.lockCanvas();
        update(mCanvas);
        values = new Values(mCanvas);
        createPaints();
        drawBackground(mCanvas);
        drawObjects(mCanvas);
        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(mCanvas);


    }
}
```

Now the collision is processed in the update:

```
private void update(Canvas c) {
    ball.update(c, checkLinesCollision(values.level1, ball.getX(), ball.getY()));
  //takes a canvas, and a boolean
}

boolean checkLinesCollision(float[] f,float x,float y){
    int c = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < f.length; i+=4){
        float x1 = f[i];
        float y1 = f[i+1];
        float x2 = f[i+2];
        float y2 = f[i+3];

        if (x> x1 && x<x2 && y>y1 && y>y2){

            c++;

        }
    }
        if(c>0){return true;}else{return false;}

}
```

the values for the level

```
 float yLow = c.getHeight()-c.getHeight()/4;

    level1 = new float[]{0,yLow,c.getWidth(),yLow,
                      40,c.getHeight()/2,300,c.getHeight()/2};
```

ball update function:

```
public void update(Canvas c, boolean b) {

    if(b){

        dy=-dy;
        b = false;
    }
    y -= dy;
    dy--; 
}
```

Now according to the logcat the problem is in the main update function.
I think that I am using the wrong function, what can I do to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is logcat saying?

Comment: @0gravity that i have android runtime problem, the exact place is   ball.update(c, checkLinesCollision(values.level1, ball.getX(), ball.getY()));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. Apparently the problem was with the float array; in my app, i declared the float array in a constructor. After a long time of researching on the web and rechecking my logcat, i found that you cannot declare an array in the constructor. all i did was moving the float array outside of the constructor and everything was alright, even though i found the solution, i am not sure why you cannot declare it in the constructor..